# Increasing integers at specific time with elapsed time

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that will work as an "infomercial" in a separate window.

What i have are two integers (x and y) that both increase at the same time, in this case every 5 seconds. With the increasing values i need a timer displayed at the same time, that can show the elapsed time of how long the program has been running. I want to be albe to start and pause the program
So far i have an infinite while loop running where the values are increased every 5 seconds with `time.sleep(5)`. I have tried implementing a timer in the form of a `time.time()`, and get it to work with the increments. I have also added buttons but don't work. I'm using `tkinter` as gui obtion.

How am i supposed to make it work? with threading?

```
import time
from tkinter import *
import math

usage = 0
yearly = 0
cubik = 0
price = 0

root = Tk()
root.title("Usage of fluid")

root.geometry("300x400")

var = IntVar()
var1 = IntVar()
var2 = StringVar()
var3 = StringVar()
var4 = StringVar()

def update_timeText():
    current= time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    timeText.configure(text=current)
    root.after(1000, update_timeText)

def start():
    global state
    state = True

def pause():
    global state
    state = False

def exist():
    root.destroy()


frame = LabelFrame(root, text="Liter", font=30)
frame.pack(fill = "both", expand="yes")

l = Label(frame, textvariable=var, font=20)
l.pack(pady = 3)

frame2 = LabelFrame(root, text="price from use", font=30)
frame2.pack(fill = "both", expand= "yes")

l2 = Label(frame2, textvariable=var1, font=16)
l2.pack(side = LEFT)

l3 = Label(frame2, text="dollars", font=16)
l3.pack(side=LEFT)

frame3 = LabelFrame(root, text="yearly", font=30)
frame3.pack(fill = "both", expand="yes")

m3 = Label(frame3, textvariable=var2, font=16, wraplength=0)
m3.pack(side=TOP)

l4 = Label(frame3, text="Liter", font=16)
l4.pack(side=TOP)

l5 = Label(frame3, text="m3", font=16)
l5.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill="both")

m4 = Label(frame3, textvariable=var3, font=16, wraplength=0)
m4.pack(side=BOTTOM)

frame4 = LabelFrame(root, text='runtime', font=30)
frame4.pack(fill = "both", expand="yes")

timeText= Label(frame4, text="", font=16)
timeText.pack()

startButton = Button(frame4, text='Start', command=start)
startButton.pack()

pauseButton = Button(frame4, text='Pause', command=pause)
pauseButton.pack()

quitButton = Button(frame4, text='Quit', command=quit)
quitButton.pack()


while True:
    var.set(usage)
    usage += 300
    var1.set(round(price,1))
    price+= 10
    var2.set(yearly)
    var3.set(round(cubik,1))
    yearly += 300
    cubik += 0.1
    time.sleep(5)
    update_timeText()
    root.update_idletasks()

##update_timeText()
##root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Post the code you have tried. Tkinter will block gui untill your funtion return unless you use callbacks/threading etc.

Comment: Please include your code in the question so we can see what you have tried so far.

Comment: You can't `time.sleep` inside a GUI program. The `mainloop()` has to keep looping multiple times per second, or no events get processed—your display updates are invisible, your buttons don't work, and eventually the OS puts up an hourglass or beachball or whatever. Look at the `after` function, which lets you ask tkinter to run any function you want 5 seconds from now.

Comment: Sorry. Code uploaded @Mick_

Comment: code uploaded @mypetlion